# Not able to Download file from s3 bucket inside emr notebook running with pyspark kernel

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I have made a cluster of emr having spark and some other tools but when launching emr notebook and trying to access the s3 bucket file, I am not able to download the file from s3 getting permission denied error. All the default role has access for s3.

[image]

Comment: Check your EMR_EC2 role. Does that role have access to `test-emr-bucket-111`?

Comment: yes i have given AWSS3FullAccess to the EMR_EC2 Role

Comment: this EMR cluster is in private subnet or public subnet?

Comment: public subnet only

Comment: Permission denied is on emr write side, not s3 read. Try to download it to `/tmp/` location

Comment: can i put that as answer and will you accept that pls??

Comment: definitely, sure I will do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Permission denied is on emr write side, not s3 read. Try to download it to `/tmp/` location